# If I select a checkbox, I deactivate another

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox, radio-button

Update 10/21/2021 - I still need a resolution.

Here's the situation: As you can see in the visual example below. I have four - buttons radio - I need to make an event where when I select the option "NO" of the compo  I automatically disable the two selections in the field .

If "YES" is selected, the two other selections must remain active. My problem is because the four stamps are "radio buttons" and not a checkbox.

Visual example:

<-- IVF fertilization -->

⬜ Yes
⬜ No

<-- if IVF ovum -->

⬜ Own
⬜ From a donor

And the third code is the HTML part, for analysis.

I have this snippet:

```html
Code 1
Base PHP code I'm using.

<!-- IVF fertilization -->
<div class='col-sm-4'>
    <?=_('IVF fertilization')?>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" id="yesFe" name="niptData_ivfFertilization" value='1' 
            <?=($_SESSION['REQUEST']['niptData_ivfFertilization-required0allow'] == '1' OR $registration->test->data->ivfFertilization == '1') ? 'checked' : ''?>
        > 
        <label for="yesFe" class='smallLabel'><?=_('Yes')?></label> 
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" id="noFe" name="niptData_ivfFertilization" value='0' 
            <?=($_SESSION['REQUEST']['niptData_ivfFertilization-required0allow'] == '0' OR $registration->test->data->ivfFertilization == '0') ? 'checked' : ''?>
        > 
        <label for="noFe" class='smallLabel'><?=_('No')?></label> 
    </div>
</div>

<!-- if IVF ovum -->
<div class='col-sm-4'>
    <?=_('If IVF ovum')?>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" id="ownOv" name="niptData_ovum" value='1' data-validation="" 
            <?=($_SESSION['OPTIONAL']['niptData_ovum'] == '1' OR $registration->test->data->ovum == '1') ? 'checked' : ''?>
        > 
        <label for="ownOv" class='smallLabel'><?=_('Own')?></label> 
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" id="fromADonor" name="niptData_ovum" value='2' data-validation="" 
            <?=($_SESSION['OPTIONAL']['niptData_ovum'] == '2' OR $registration->test->data->ovum == '2') ? 'checked' : ''?>
        > 
        <label for="fromADonor" class='smallLabel'><?=_('From a donor')?></label> 
    </div>
    <br>
</div>



CODE 2
Script that working to solve the problem.


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#new_user_form *').filter(':radio').change(function() {
            if(this.id=='noFe' && this.value=='0' && $(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('#new_user_form *').filter(':radio').each(function(){
                    if(this.id=='noFe' && this.value=='0') {
                    } else {
                        $(this).attr("checked",false);
                    }
                });
            }
            if((this.id=='ownOv' || this.id=='fromADonor' && this.value=='0') {
                var checkedId = this.id;
                var checkedOrNot = $(this).is(':checked');
                $('#new_user_form *').filter(':radio').each(function(){
                    if(this.id==checkedId && (this.value=='1' || this.value=='2')) {
                        if(checkedOrNot) {
                            $(this).attr("disabled",true);
                        } else {
                            $(this).attr("disabled",false);
                        }
                    }
                });
</script>



CODE 3
HTML code that was asked of me.


<div class="col-sm-4">
                Pregnancy<span class="required">*</span>
                <div class="has-error">
                <input type="radio" id="yesFe" name="niptData_ivfFertilization-required0allow" value="1" data-validation="required" class="error" style="border-color: rgb(185, 74, 72);"> 
                <label for="yesFe" class="smallLabel">Yes</label> 
                <span class="help-block form-error">Required field</span></div>

                <div class="has-success">
                <input type="radio" id="noFe" name="niptData_ivfFertilization-required0allow" value="0" data-validation="required" class="valid" style=""> 
                <label for="noFe" class="smallLabel">No</label> 
                </div>
            </div>


<div class="col-sm-4">
                if FIVET, ovum<span class="optional"></span>
                <div>
                <input type="radio" id="ownOv" name="niptData_ovum" value="1" data-validation=""> 
                <label for="ownOv" class="smallLabel">Own</label> 
                </div>

                <div>
                <input type="radio" id="fromADonor" name="niptData_ovum" value="2" data-validation=""> 
                <label for="fromADonor" class="smallLabel"> 
As a donor</label> 
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
```

Comment: I can't see no checkboxes in your code, only radiobuttons. As far as I understand, Radiobuttons behave like you described, so what is the issue?

Comment: Maybe I expressed myself wrongly. Yes, they are normal radio pulses! I want that when selecting the pulsating "no" -> (<input type="radio" id="noFe" ....) I automatically deselect the two pulsatings of the snippet -> ( <!-- if IVF ovum -- > ). And that they are enabled only when the first option "yes" -> is selected ( <input type="radio" id="yesFe" ).

Comment: I actually need the script to make it all work.  :)

Comment: This can only be done with JS. There is no JS code in your question. Can you please add what you tried? Also please post the actual HTML and not this server-side code.

Comment: I believe I inserted the missing parts in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if I understand right but here is solution:

1- I deleted the codes that not inportant for that issue
2- I added class name "secondis" to elements that I will disable after checkbox clicked

Hope you got what you wanted

```js
$("#yesFe").click(function(){
if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {$("#secondissue").show();$(".secondis").prop('disabled', false);}
else {$("#secondissue").hide();$(".secondis").prop('disabled', true);}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  Pregnancy<span class="required">*</span>
  <div class="has-error">
    <input type="checkbox" id="yesFe" name="niptData_ivfFertilization-required0allow" value="1" data-validation="required" class="error " style="border-color: rgb(185, 74, 72);"> 
    <label for="yesFe" class="smallLabel">Sì</label> 
    <span class="help-block form-error">Required field</span></div>

  <div class="has-success">
    <input type="checkbox" id="noFe" name="niptData_ivfFertilization-required0allow" value="0" data-validation="required" class="valid" style=""> 
    <label for="noFe" class="smallLabel">No</label> 
  </div>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-4" id ="secondissue" style="display:none">
  Se FIVET, ovuli<span class="optional"></span>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="ownOv" name="niptData_ovum" value="1"  class="secondis" data-validation="" > 
    <label for="ownOv" class="smallLabel">Propri</label> 
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="fromADonor" name="niptData_ovum" class="secondis" value="2" data-validation=""  > 
    <label for="fromADonor" class="smallLabel">Da donatrice</label> 
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a small problem yet! In fact, in the "IFV Fertilization" box the type is radio and not a checkbox. So when in the code I make this change to radio and in output I click on the "NO" option first, everything is OK, but if I start by clicking on "Yes", it shows me the two selections of the frame "if IFV ovum", which is OK, but if I click on NO again, it doesn't hide the two options I started to see when I clicked on the YES selection.
How could it solve?
I deeply appreciate your availability, thank you.